# Vulkan load vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT

Tags: vulkan

I am getting into Vulkan and stumbled on my first problem. When trying to create a debug report callback (validation layers and debug extensions are available on my intel hd vulkan driver, at least it says so), it fails telling me `vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT` is an unresolved symbol. When trying to get the function pointer it fails telling me `vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT` is already defined.

Which it is, in the Vulkan header. I could set VK_NO_PROTOTYPES but then I would have to load everything by hand. Is there a way around this? Just using a different name for the function pointer won't work, since I am using Vulkan-Hpp and it uses `vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT` as it is.
Is this a driver bug, telling me debug extensions are available, but there are not?

Btw, I am using VS2015.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Weird, I don't see the `vulkan.hpp` to even use that extension command though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's normal. `vulkan.h` defines them as a global functions. But the loader commands obviously return function **pointer**.

Normally you would just use a different name you like. But I like to have the canonical names too...

I solve it by **defining** the function myself (using the **declaration** from `vulkan.h`) which in turn calls the loaded pointer:

```
VKAPI_ATTR VkResult VKAPI_CALL vkCommandEXT( /*...*/ ){
    return fpCommandEXT( /*...*/ );
}
```

(Shameless self-promotion) Like so:
https://github.com/krOoze/Hello_Triangle/blob/8227220/ErrorHandling.h#L181

I make the command to self-load on its first use — if you don't like that, in older commit I had more conventional loader:
https://github.com/krOoze/Hello_Triangle/blob/699ab57/HelloTriangle.cpp#L731

PS:
Khronos themselves just added loader code that illustrates that nicely:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/blob/1.0/src/ext_loader/vulkan_ext.c

If you handle multiple `VkInstance`s or `VkDevice`s the loaded functions have to be dispatched to the correct instance or device. For example, I do that (likely inefficiently) here:
https://github.com/krOoze/Hello_Triangle/blob/a691de5/ExtensionLoader.h

Comment: Just another shameless self promotion ! My Vk loader: https://github.com/AlessandroBorges/Bor_Vulkan/blob/master/Vulkan/jni/vulkan_wrapper.h and https://github.com/AlessandroBorges/Bor_Vulkan/blob/master/Vulkan/jni/vulkan_wrapper.cpp . The cpp is update up to Vulkan 1.0.7. I'll fix it to 1.0.21.1 soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, couldn't find solution so i solved it this way
*(might be wrong, but i just want to share in case it will help somebody)*:

```
struct DebugDispatch {
    //KHRONOS
    PFN_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT = 0;
    PFN_vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT = 0;
    //LUNARG
    PFN_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT = 0;
    PFN_vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT = 0;
}

VKAPI_ATTR vk::Bool32 VKAPI_CALL debugReportCallback(...){...}
VKAPI_ATTR vk::Bool32 VKAPI_CALL debugUtilsMessengerCallback(...){...}

enum class ValidationFlagsBits : unsigned int {
    NONE = 0,
    KHRONOS = 1,
    LUNARG = 1 << 1
};

typedef vk::Flags<ValidationFlagsBits> ValidationFlags;

void Example(){
    ...

    vk::Instance instance;
    instance = vk::createInstance(...);

    DebugDispatch debug_dispatch;
    vk::DebugReportCallbackEXT debug_report_callback;
    vk::DebugUtilsMessengerEXT debug_utils_messenger;
    
    if(validation_flags & ValidationFlagsBits::KHRONOS){
        debug_dispatch.vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT = 
            (PFN_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT)instance.getProcAddr("vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT");
        debug_dispatch.vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT =
            (PFN_vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT)instance.getProcAddr("vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT");
        
        vk::DebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT create_info{};
        create_info.messageSeverity = ...;
        create_info.messageType = ...;
        create_info.pfnUserCallback = reinterpret_cast<PFN_vkDebugUtilsMessengerCallbackEXT>(&debugUtilsMessengerCallback);

        debug_utils_messenger = instance.createDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(create_info, nullptr, debug_dispatch);
    }
    if(validation_flags & ValidationFlagsBits::LUNARG){
        debug_dispatch.vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT =
            (PFN_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT)instance.getProcAddr("vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");
        debug_dispatch.vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT =
            (PFN_vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT)instance.getProcAddr("vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");

        vk::DebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT create_info{};
        create_info.flags = ...;
        create_info.pfnCallback = reinterpret_cast<PFN_vkDebugReportCallbackEXT>(&debugReportCallback);

        debug_report_callback = instance.createDebugReportCallbackEXT(create_info, nullptr, debug_dispatch);
    }

    ...

    if(validation_flags & ValidationFlagsBits::KHRONOS){
        instance.destroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(debug_utils_messenger, nullptr, debug_dispatch);
    }
    if(validation_flags & ValidationFlagsBits::LUNARG){
        instance.destroyDebugReportCallbackEXT(debug_report_callback, nullptr, debug_dispatch);
    }
    instance.destroy();
}
```